# Is there anyway to create an executable backup of a folder?

Tags: backup, workspaces, executable, ros

I have to create an executable to restore a workspace back to a certain stage (offline so files need to be stored with the executable). I know the shell commands I'd require but I'm not sure how to package this all into a nice executable with the files?

what I am requiring is:

- delete existing folder if exists
- copy files to this location
- catkin_make (it's a ROS workspace)
- reboot

Essentially I have to make an *idiot-proof* way to restore the software to a version with just a double click.

Thanks if anyone can assist me :)

**EDIT**
I have looked into unzipsfx and have found that it's not well documented and from spending hours on it I could not get it to work.

Comment: You may be able to do something with `unzipsfx`.

Comment: @SHawarden this will create a self extracting zip right? That will extract to a location specified? O.o Am I able to add a script or shell command for it to execute?

Comment: The [AUTORUN COMMAND](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-unzipsfx#lbAJ) section indicates that you should be able to, yes.

Comment: [the link](http://www.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/) gives a 404 :/

Comment: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-unzipsfx/#lbAJ

Comment: I have been trying to get unzipsfx to work for some time now and cannot, could someone who knows how to do it please submit an answer with source